# No Module Found "elasticsearch"

Tags: elasticsearch, jupyter

Installed elasticsearch by pip but notebook was throwing error like no module found.
i got it fixed by restarting the jupyter notebook. but iam curious how it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem with environments. The jupyter notebook you previously used, did not use the same Python environment as where you've installed elasticsearch. You can always check which version you are using with

`which python`

in your terminal. Or the Windows CMD equivalent

`where python`

Comment: I do not have virtual environment, and I did pip in jupyter notebook itself. with command !pip install elasticsearch , it should be working without any restart rt?

Comment: Did you try to restart your kernel after your `!pip install` command?

Comment: It is not a guarantee that an installation goes perfectly, since not every system is 100% the same. Sometimes something in the background keeps stuck and hanging. Turning a system off and on again will reset the state.